# Checking a datetime index value

Tags: python, pandas

Never figured this one out.

A datetime index in a dataframe is selected by df.loc['2022-07-18 15:15:00'] or iloc or whatever but how can I perform a conditional check on the **time** in an datetime to create a column value for a specific time?
i.e.

```
if index.time = '***16:00:00':
  df['end'] = True
```

I don't know how to use wildcards in this instance either.

Comment: can you provide a reproducible dataframe sample? The method will depend on the exact type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a datetime index, you can use:

```
df['end'] = df.index == '16:00:00'  # also works with '16:00'
```

example output:

```
                     col    end
2022-07-20 04:52:06    0  False
2022-07-20 10:16:24    1  False
2022-07-20 10:41:42    2  False
2022-07-20 16:00:00    3   True
2022-07-20 19:07:42    4  False
```

reproducible input:

```
from pandas import Timestamp
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': {Timestamp('2022-07-20 04:52:06'): 0,
                           Timestamp('2022-07-20 10:16:24'): 1,
                           Timestamp('2022-07-20 10:41:42'): 2,
                           Timestamp('2022-07-20 16:00:00'): 3,
                           Timestamp('2022-07-20 19:07:42'): 4}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dt` to subset the data frame `df` as follows:

```
df[(df.time.dt.hour==16) & (df.time.dt.minute==0) & (df.time.dt.second==0)]
```

as outlines in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html).

As an example, take the  frame

```
df         = pd.DataFrame({'col_1' : [1,2,3,4], 'col_2': [65, 32, 78, 33]})
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime([1658246400, 1645621805, 1572333181, 1270483200], unit='s')
df
```

[image]

and observe the sub-frame:

[image]